# Other options besides using HOVER inside my CSS

Tags: css

This is my Class inside my CSS.............

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 and jQuery..........

```
#ImageBoxNextImage:hover
 {
background-image: url(http://www.eRate.co.za/jquery/imagebox/next_image.jpg);
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
background-position: right bottom;
 }
```

Only when i HOVER over my item it will display the Next_Image.jpg. What are my other option i can use beside HOVER. I want the image to always be there not only on HOVER.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, regarding "CSS jQuery class" in your title. Have a read of http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200902/its_class_not_css_class/
You're defining a CSS rule and it doesn't have much to do with jQuery or ASP.NET. 
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove :hover, it will apply to the element at all times...

Answer (score 1):

pseudoclass :hover makes this style applicable only for hovered element. Remove ":hover".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you want to switch the image or not.

If you want to switch the image after mouseover, you need to use javascript to retain the image:

```
<div id="ImageBoxNextImage" onmouseover="changeBackground(this)">content</div>

function changeBackground(e){
   e.style.background = "url(http://www.eRate.co.za/jquery/imagebox/next_image.jpg)";
}
```

If you don't need to switch the image, you can just delete the ":hover" of your css class.